# Moonlight-Mono for Raring 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, software-installation, moonlight

Is there a method or location to install Moonlight on Ubuntu Raring 13.04?

Comment: Just wondering whether these are safe to use? Can anyone maybe verify?

Answer (score 1):

I found a [blog post](http://blog.mbirgin.com/?c=page&ID=326&t=howtoinstallmoonlightsilverlightonubuntu) that references an [alternate download location](http://mokeke.sytes.net/downloads/linux/Novell_Moonlight/). That location is on a dynamic DNS host, currently somewhere in Japan, likely a personal page. In case it goes down, I'll reference the download links below. They're all files in Google Docs.

While the instructions from the blog work for me, YMMV. I have the following disclaimers:

1. I have NO way to tell what the origin of these files is. They may be perfectly legitimate, or they may contain malware.
2. This appears to be a build of Moonlight v3, which the mono site [describes](http://www.mono-project.com/MoonlightRoadmap) as an upcoming release. It may not be what you expect.

With that, here are the current links:

- Chrome

  - [novell-moonlight-3.99.0.3-i586.crx](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0xVGvAbM6ZkQzlDSFh4VVliM28/edit?usp=sharing)
  - [novell-moonlight-3.99.0.3-x86_64.crx](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0xVGvAbM6ZkVXlBTG9oLVBQVXc/edit?usp=sharing)
- Firefox

  - [novell-moonlight-3.99.0.3-i586.xpi](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0xVGvAbM6ZkanVKSm9adWlraVk/edit?usp=sharing)
  - [novell-moonlight-3.99.0.3-x86_64.xpi](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0xVGvAbM6ZkcTN3b1R1NVI1SVE/edit?usp=sharing)