# How to enable Moonlight/Silverlight 5 on firefox?

Tags: firefox, moonlight

I have installed moonlight from this post here: https://askubuntu.com/a/327862/188878

the problem is, the application/website I am trying to use "requires" silverlight 5. is there anyway to trick the website into thinking I have silverlight 5 so that I can at least try it out and see if it works. the website is www.dayforcehcm.com and its so that I can do my scheduling at work. If this doesnt work, its a near deal breaker for me and ubuntu..

or is there any other sources of a silverlight alternative/way I could access this website?

thanks.

EDIT: had to remove some code because post became too long. the following code is from pipelight installed on firefox 23 running on ubuntu 13.04

checking the terminal output shows lots of errors, so perhaps this site actually is incompatible:

```
fixme:thread:NtQueryInformationThread info class 16 not supported yet
fixme:thread:NtQueryInformationThread info class 16 not supported yet
fixme:module:GetModuleHandleExW should pin refcount for 0x240000
fixme:urlmon:Uri_GetPropertyBSTR (0x5e61a78)->(6 0x63dee4 4)
fixme:thread:GetThreadPreferredUILanguages 48, 0x63e580, (nil) 0x63e578
fixme:thread:GetThreadPreferredUILanguages 48, 0x63e580, (nil) 0x63e578
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unimplemented caltype 2
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 56
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 55
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 49
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 50
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 51
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 52
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 53
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 54
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 21
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 22
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 23
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 24
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 25
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 26
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 27
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 28
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 29
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 30
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 31
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 32
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 33
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 34
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 35
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 36
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 37
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 38
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 39
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 40
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 41
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 42
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 43
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 44
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 45
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 46
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unimplemented caltype 4
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unimplemented caltype 4
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 57
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 57
fixme:nls:EnumTimeFormatsW Unknown time format (2)
fixme:nls:EnumTimeFormatsW Unknown time format (2)
[PIPELIGHT] Unscheduled event timer
```

I tried wine today, installed firefox 23, silverlight 5. Visited the website and seemed to get the same errors that pipelight got.. perhaps this is something that is wines fault then?

```
fixme:advapi:RegisterTraceGuidsW (0x1eb1f87, 0x1f50118, {aa087e0e-0b35-4e28-8f3a-440c3f51eef1}, 1, 0x33eaac, (null), (null), 0x1f50118,): stub
fixme:advapi:CreateProcessAsUserW 0x11c L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Silverlight\\5.1.20513.0\\agcp.exe" L"agcp.exe 109 276" (nil) (nil) 1 0x00004000 (nil) (null) 0x33ee30 0x33ee20 - semi- stub
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
fixme:file:K32GetMappedFileNameW (0xffffffff, 0x4015f4, 0x50e1d4, 520): stub
fixme:module:GetModuleHandleExW should pin refcount for 0x1e40000
fixme:win:GetRawInputDeviceList (pRawInputDeviceList=(nil), puiNumDevices=0x33cb54, cbSize=8) stub!
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:urlmon:Uri_GetPropertyBSTR (0x27a6198)->(6 0x33e224 4)
fixme:process:GetNumaHighestNodeNumber (0x33ecc0): stub
fixme:thread:GetThreadPreferredUILanguages 48, 0x33e8c0, (nil) 0x33e8b8
fixme:thread:GetThreadPreferredUILanguages 48, 0x33e8c0, (nil) 0x33e8b8
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unhandled dwOption 4
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption Unknown dwOption 10
fixme:wininet:INET_QueryOption INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION stub
**fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unimplemented caltype 1
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unimplemented caltype 1
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unimplemented caltype 2
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 56
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 55
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 49
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 50
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 51
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 52
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 53
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 54
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 21
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 22
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 23
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 24
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 25
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 26
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 27
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 28
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 29
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 30
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 31
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 32
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 33
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 34
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 35
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 36
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 37
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 38
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 39
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 40
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 41
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 42
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 43
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 44
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 45
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 46**
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unimplemented caltype 4
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unimplemented caltype 4
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 57
fixme:time:GetCalendarInfoW Unknown caltype 57
fixme:nls:EnumTimeFormatsW Unknown time format (2)
fixme:nls:EnumTimeFormatsW Unknown time format (2)
```

EDIT:

Just wanted to update to say that I tried this again with the newest release of wine, winetricks, wine-gecko, and wine-mono installed and it worked flawlessly. no caltype errors, no useragent spoofing required. Had to create a 32 bit wine prefix, and installed dotnet45 using winetricks. Visited websites using firefox. for reference, this was wine 1.735, winetricks 20141130, wine_gecko 2.34, wine-mono 4.5.4. I can confirm that this now works on Ubuntu 14.04 and an up to date Arch build.

Comment: I've updated my answer with other options.

Comment: An update -- I have been able to get the combination of wine, firefox, dotnet45 (via winetricks), and silverlight 5 to work successfully.

Answer (score 18):

## Using Pipelight

My answer is credits Webupd8: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/08/pipelight-use-silverlight-in-your-linux.html

You can use Pipelight to provide you with Silverlight support.

To install it:#

Make sure to close your browser first, if not you will need to run an extra command.

### From the terminal:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ehoover/compholio
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:mqchael/pipelight
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pipelight
```

### From the GUI:

- Add the repositories to your software sources:

  sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ehoover/compholio
  sudo apt-add-repository ppa:mqchael/pipelight

After refreshing your sources, install [pipelight [image: Install pipelight]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pipelight)
*If this icon doesn't work simply search for it in the Software Center.*

#### If you kept the browser open, run:

```
rm -rf ~/.wine-pipelight/
```

### Next step, make sites that block Linux work:

Use one of these two addons (F:

- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/uacontrol/
- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-overrider/

Or this one (Chrome):

- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg

### If you get slow playback, see:

- https://answers.launchpad.net/pipelight/+faq/2364
- https://answers.launchpad.net/pipelight/+faq/2356

---

## Alternative solutions:

### Using a Windows browser on top of Wine.

You can probably use Silverlight 5 on top of a Windows Browser using Wine. I have not tested this option but it is pretty reasonable and straight forward.

- Install [wine [image: Install wine]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/wine)
- Download and install your browser.
- Download and install Silverlight for Windows as you normally would do on Windows.
- Live long and prosper.

### Using Windows in a Virtual Machine.

If you don't want to give up Linux, but can't get anything else to work, this is the best bet. You need a valid copy of Windows however as I won't give steps for pirating.

- Install [virtualbox [image: Install virtualbox]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/virtualbox)
- VMWare Player is an option as well, as well as Qemu, etc; but I highly recommend Virtual Box.
- Download and install the Virtual Box extensions (optional).
- Using a valid Copy of Windows, create a new Virtual Machine in Virtual Box.
- Install your browser of choice (if necessary) or use Internet Explorer.
- Install Silverlight.
- Enjoy your coffee or beverage of choice (absolutely necessary step!). Skipping this step will result in the process not being as rewarding as intended.

Comment: thanks for the awesome reply, I followed your steps but am unable to see the addon in firefox, even after removing the config directory.. I'm not sure whats gone wrong, all of the packages are installed EDIT: found it in plugins. it currently says pipelight error! check the terminal output, so im going to investigate.

Comment: starting firefox from the terminal doesnt prove helpful either. The first time I started firefox I seemed to get a brief wine error window popup, but it doesnt seem to happen again. A `sudo apt-get purge pipelight && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get install pipelight` doesnt seem to change things. Also, I am running firefox 23

Comment: ok i seemed to have fixed things sort of. see the first post

Comment: @Paul Pipelight is not a Firefox addon, but rather a plugin. Make sure that you have the plugin enabled in your Firefox plugins.

Comment: yes, i do have it enabled. It seems to run. I am able to view the silverlight test video. But it seems to run into serious errors on the website i need it for. Unfortunately, theres no way to test out the silverlight without logging in and you need official credentials to do this so I am unable to have other people test it on their setups.

Comment: Have you tried any of the other options I suggested?

Comment: sorry havent gotten a chance to try the wine options, i will now. I was hoping to avoid having to use wine

Comment: alright, i've now tried wine, see above for the unsuccessful results..

Comment: It might be possible to work around those errors with the correct dlls. I would probably not get an answer on that part back to you in a timely fashion though, I must admit :(

Comment: alright, thanks.  i'll try to contact the company in the meantime and see if they can offer any help

Comment: unfortunately it seems like support from the developers is non-existent. I'm not sure if the software is abandoned, but i think it will be soon along with silverlight. Probably why it was cheap for my employer to use

Comment: I just installed the 'pipelight' and the silverlight is working fine in mu Ubuntu 13.10. thanks

Comment: i used a different repository - `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipelight/stable` instead of the two that you have mentioned. It worked on my firefox on Ubuntu 14.04. But it made no difference in chrome.

Comment: Here is why Pipelight does not work on chrome - http://pipelight.net/cms/chrome-chromium.html

Comment: why don't you use the ppa:pipelight/stable as provided in the link you have given http://www.webupd8.org/2013/08/pipelight-use-silverlight-in-your-linux.html? I used this ppa and it works fine, no issues on multiple distros (13.10-14.10)

Answer (score 2):

**CLOSE FIREFOX BEFORE THIS INSTALATION OR YOU WILL EXPERIENCE PROBLEMS**

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends pipelight-multi
sudo pipelight-plugin --update
```

The following commands install system wide. To install to the user only do not use sudo.

To enable silverlight system wide

```
sudo pipelight-plugin --enable silverlight
```

for the windows version of adobe flash system wide

```
sudo pipelight-plugin --enable flash
```

for widevine systemwide

```
sudo pipelight-plugin --enable widevine
```

And there's even a Unity3D plugin

```
sudo pipelight-plugin --enable unity3d
```

This does not work for google-chrome or chromium, only firefox.

source

http://www.webupd8.org/2013/08/pipelight-use-silverlight-in-your-linux.

Comment: not working I still get install silverlight option when I open .aspx webpage

Comment: @Creator did silverlight install fully and is the plugin enabled in Firefox under addons > plugins?

Comment: I followed these steps http://www.itworld.com/article/2697813/install-silverlight-alternative-pipelight-in-ubuntu-14-04.html and after that I restarted firfox then plugin was wroking and is shown with firefox, but now I might have 2 pipelight-sliverlight plugins can you tell me how to remove it.

Comment: @Creator if it works and there are no issues, I wouldn't touch it for now. In the past, i've had both installed and didn't have any issues. The funny thing is that I believe the ppa from that article doesn't supply the pipelight package as that is now provided through apt-get and pipelight-multi is from the ppa but like I said, you may get a warning about having more than one pipelight installed but if it's working fine it shouldn't need to be fixed.

Comment: https://launchpad.net/~pipelight/+archive/ubuntu/stable

Answer (score 1):

I followed the steps, but my Ubuntu 14.04 would not want to do the install pipelight. 
I then switched the `/etc/ubuntu/source.list` to use `us.archive.ubuntu.com` and after that all went smooth. Maybe it helps someone else to avoid a lot of headaches.. See [this question on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release) for further reference.