# How to get Silverlight and Flash 10+ to work in Chromebook and Ubuntu 12.04 with Firefox

Tags: firefox, flash, chromebook, glibc

I would like to watch content from many of TV-station's streaming services. First I need Flashplayer 10+ with Firefox and then Silverlight (Mac and Windows are supported I think, Chromebook is not, right?).

I have:
- Samsung Chromebook
- In the Chromebook Ubuntu 12.04 installed (looks to be very minimal set up)
- In the Ubuntu I am using Firefox (I didn't success with Chrome installation on this Chromebook ;-) :-D - Fun!)

I have tried to:
- as "root" to run sudo rpm -i flash-plugin-11.2.....i386.rpm
- solve the problem when running the previous rpm fails. It says I need glibc >= 2.4 and also bin/sh is needed (what???).
- due to need of glibc I updated my repository at /etc/apt/sources.list but finally it says that apt-get cannot locate package glibc.
- install by apt-get "build-essential" to get glibc but it didn't help at all. Glibc is not updated.

There is no success :-(. I cannot even dream about Silverlight before getting to work something so basics like Flashplayer.

If you could help me to go forward it would be very nice :-). I am dreaming of getting everything what I ever need to work with my Chromebook except photoshopping (It's done by my Mac)

Thanks!

With best regards,
Hermann

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not be installing .rpm on Ubuntu.

Second, to install flash

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

Silverlight is not available for Linux. The closest is moonlight or pipelight

See [How to enable Moonlight/Silverlight 5 on firefox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342035/how-to-enable-moonlight-silverlight-5-on-firefox)

Not sure if it works on alternate browsers. Last time I tried moonlight is was a bit buggy.

Comment: I tried to run the command but it says "Unable to locate package flashplugin-installer". I think I have some problem with my repository and I just cannot solve what is that problem. Maybe this Ubuntu version on this platform is too minimal?

Comment: You need to enable a few repositories, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies

Comment: Hi! I have now update by all possible ways my sources.list, updated it and so on. Always it says "*** has no installation candidate" or "package is not available... ...is referred by to another package" etc. I have tried to find out and install flashplugin-installer, wime and many other thing joining to this case. Could it be so that my whole installation is broken or there is some major misconfiguration? This is brand new Chromebook and I did everything correctly when installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. This is bit depressing, I have to say. :-)

Comment: You need to go to the ubuntu software center, click on "edit" and select "software sources" from the dropdown menu. From there, you need to make sure to have "multiverse" selected as the flashplugin installer is provided by multiverse.